# Insert record, auto add datetime getdate()

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a simple sql insert C# statement, that works! However when I add a column for datetime getdate(), no nulls, insert fails. I have tried and looked at various articles, and i just cant get it.

Here is my code!

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
                "My_DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                            "INSERT INTO TestTable1 VALUES(@FirstName, @Email)"))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", user.FirstName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", user.Email);                    
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

This works, so i add a new column Date using SQL Server Manager, with datetime and getdate() allow nulls not checked.

So this adds date and time to any existing records, but when i try from Form submit, its not working.

Error is:
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: Share the code which throwing error.

Comment: It might be nice if you were clear about what you mean by "with datetime and getdate() allow nulls not checked". Don't make us guess.

Comment: At the very least, supply the columns name into the `INSERT` you're sending. Never leave it to the server to guess what do you want.

Comment: @Alejandro thnnx you where right, as per Fabio's answer. P

Answer (score 5):

If list of columns not provided in the INSERT INTO statement, SQL Server expected values for all columns

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)

> If the values in the Value list are not in the same order as the
>   columns in the table **or do not have a value for each column in the
>   table, column_list must be used to explicitly specify the column that
>   stores each incoming value**.

But your query provide only two columns

Add values for all columns in the table(except IDENTITY column if used) in the VALUES section

```sql
INSERT INTO TestTable1 VALUES (@FirstName, @Email, GETDATE())
```

or add list of inserted columns and default values will be used for other columns

```sql
INSERT INTO TestTable1 (FirstName, Email) VALUES (@FirstName, @Email)
```

Answer (score -1):

> get Time and date with DateTime.Now.

```
System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

> add it as parameter in the query
>
> Your code should be like this.

```
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["My_DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TestTable1 VALUES (@FirstName,@Email,@DateTime)"))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", user.FirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", user.Email);                    
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime",System.DateTime.Now);                    
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Trying to pass in a datetime as a string as never a good idea.

Comment: then what is the better way to do it ?

Comment: You just pass in the datetime instance directly.

Comment: Also, you are assuming that the GETDATE() function on sql will return the same datetime value as the System.DateTime.Now. However, this may not be correct since sql server is often used by programs on different computers, so it's very possible that the program is running in an entirely different time zone then the sql server.